# Biblatex "Ibid." not working with shorthand

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

In my bibliography I have a book with a `shorthand` and I'm using the `biblatex` package with `citestyle=authoryear-ibid`, so that immediately repeated citations are replaced by the abbreviation ‘ibidem’.
However, that doesn't work if a book that has a `shorthand` value (see the MWE).
I would like that a citation (but **just** for books with `shorthand` field) is replaced by "Ibid." just if it is *exactly identical* to the previous one. If it isn't, the complete citation (without "Ibid.") should be printed. 
So, for example, the desired output of the MWE should be

```
¹ Q, 1, 47, 56
² Ibid.
³ Q, 1, 47, 59
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.


MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
    style=chicago-authordate,
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
    ibidpage=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @book{Quaderni,
          publisher = {Einaudi},
          year = {1977},
          title = {Quaderni del carcere},
          address = {Torino},
          author = {Gramsci, Antonio},
          shorthand = {Q},
          pagination = {none}
        }
  \end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

First sentence \footcite[1, 47, 56]{Quaderni}.
Second sentence \footcite[1, 47, 56]{Quaderni}.
Third sentence \footcite[1, 47, 59]{Quaderni}.

\end{document}
```

OUTPUT:

```
¹ Q, 1, 47, 56
² Q, 1, 47, 56
³ Q, 1, 47, 59
```

Comment: What about "ibid." for other sources without a `shorthand`? Should they behave the same w.r.t. page numbers ("ibid." only if the same page) or is this entry special? What output do you expect from https://gist.github.com/moewew/2894a43316a725b34040a223da902074

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was confused and I have now corrected. **All** the sources with a `shorthand` should print "Ibid." just if the citation is _exactly identical_ to the previous one. Sources _without_ `shorthand` should behave normally (printing just "Ibid." if the citation is _exactly identical_ to the previous one, and printing "Ibid, p. XX" if the book cited is the same as that in the previous note, but on a different page.

Comment: So, your example should give as output  
`Q, 1, 47, 56`, `Ibid.`, `Q, 1, 47, 59`,   
`KpV, p. 12`, `Ibid.`, `KpV, p. 12`,  
`Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 380`, `Ibid.`, `Ibid., p. 371`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a small modification of the `cite` bibmacro.

The original definition can be found in [`authoryear-ibid.cbx` (ll. 18-29 in v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-ibid.cbx#L18-L29). We just add the test `\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\ifloccit\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}` and issue `\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}` in the *true* branch.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=chicago-authordate,
  citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
  ibidpage=true,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\ifloccit\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Quaderni,
  publisher  = {Einaudi},
  year       = {1977},
  title      = {Quaderni del carcere},
  address    = {Torino},
  author     = {Gramsci, Antonio},
  shorthand  = {Q},
  pagination = {none},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
First sentence \footcite[1, 47, 56]{Quaderni}.
Second sentence \footcite[1, 47, 56]{Quaderni}.
Third sentence \footcite[1, 47, 59]{Quaderni}.

First sentence \footcite[12]{kant:kpv}.
Second sentence \footcite[12]{kant:kpv}.
Third sentence \footcite[13]{kant:kpv}.

First sentence \footcite[380]{sigfridsson}.
Second sentence \footcite[380]{sigfridsson}.
Third sentence \footcite[381]{sigfridsson}.
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Q, 1, 47, 56. 2 Ibid. 3 Q, 1, 47, 59. 4 KpV, p. 12. 5 Ibid. 6 KpV, p. 13. 7 Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 380. 8 Ibid. 9 Ibid., p. 381.]